# Strange shape when deleting faces

Tags: faces, mirror, topology

I am currently working on Blender Guru's Chair Modelling Tutorial.

When I delete the top faces to make a hard edge, the face on the front starts making a weird shape.

Anyone knows why? Couldn't find it out myself.

Thanks in advance,
Tobi

[image: Without deleting]
[image: deleted faces]
[image: wireframe mode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

he subdivision surface modifier is placed before the mirror. Invert them.

[image]

The reason: if before, subdivision surface will smooth vertices out of the mirror axis, so they won't join anymore.

Comment: You are clutch! Thanks dude!

Comment: Clutch? is that a good thing? I guess it must be.... :D I must start using 2.9 to get all that drag and drop goodness...

Comment: @RobinBetts : ) searched it also, but it is ok! https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Clutch

Comment: do we now call you "_clutch-lemon_" or "_lemon-clutch_"?

Comment: @batFINGER... lemon alone is hard enough to endure ; )

Comment: @RobinBetts Exactly what you need, exactly when you need it.